# Unable to get Listing of Jobs in the Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to fetch all jobs registered with the Quartz scheduler for a particular group. here is my piece of code

```
CustomSchdularFactory.getSchedulerInstance().getJobKeys(groupEquals(group));
```

here `group` is a String variable holding the name of group whose associated jobs i want to fetch.
while using the above code i am getting following error

```
The method getJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>) in the type Scheduler is not applicable for the arguments (GroupMatcher<Key<Key<T>>>)
```

i am not sure why this error is occurring as i took the reference from Quartz official documents

[ListJobs](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ListJobs)

Comment: Two years later and their documentation (in the Cookbook section) is still wrong. The accepted answer is correct. The other guys just referenced the incorrect example in the Cookbook. Maybe this works in Quartz 2.2.x, but in Quartz 2.1.x, it doesn't. The bad Cookbook example is in the Quartz 2.1.x section.

Comment: @JimTough for completeness sake, this specific issue seems to have been introduced in 2.1, where the GroupMatcher code was totally overhauled.  The same code is still in 2.2, so it will cause the same issue there.  Btw, it's always nicer to leave a quick note when you downvote, I don't put false information here on purpose, I was just still using Quartz 2.0 at the time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use jobGroupEquals instead of groupEquals

```
CustomSchdularFactory.getSchedulerInstance().getJobKeys(jobGroupEquals(group));
```

and it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use it

```
Scheduler sched = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

for(String group: sched.getJobGroupNames()) {
   for(JobKey jobKey : sched.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(group))) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Quartz.NET 3.0, I was able to get this working in asynchronous mode:

```
public static async Task RunTask() {
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);
    IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    IReadOnlyCollection<string> jgn = await sch.GetJobGroupNames(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
    foreach (string jno in jgn)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection <JobKey> jk = await sch.GetJobKeys(jobGroupEquals(jno));
        foreach (JobKey j in jk)
        {
            var currentJob = await sch.GetJobDetail(j);

            //print the properties of the current job
            Console.WriteLine(currentJob.Key.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(currentJob.Description);
        }                   
    }
}   

private static GroupMatcher<JobKey> jobGroupEquals(string jno)
{
    return GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(jno);
}
```